# Use yum to select all but some packages that begin with texlive

Tags: yum

I want to install all packages that begin with texlive- but without installing those that contain doc in their name. How can I do this using yum?

Answer (score 0):

```
yum --exclude "*doc*" install "texlive*"
```

will install all packages that start with "texlive" except those that have "doc" anywhere in the package name.

If any packages specifically require a doc package, yum may complain about missing dependencies and may refuse to install anything. Give it a try.

Good luck!